# Use of "and especially"

Tags: conjunctions

Is *and* in the following sentence optional?

> He disliked nearly all women, **and** especially the young and pretty ones.

Comment: No, it's not, because it adds to the meaning, or (in some cases,) at least to the emphasis.

Comment: e- special -ly.

Answer (score 1):

I would presume that the sentence is being used in a *literary* context. As such, the *and* emphasizes the distinct dislike that he has for young and pretty women.

There are several reasons to see this sentence as literary in style.

The basic content is (i.e. a terse version of the sentence):

> He dislikes most pretty, young women.

The substitution of *nearly all* for most is to emphasize the extensiveness of his dislike of women.

The addition of the *and* is to emphasize that the young, pretty women is nearly a distinct category of people that he hates.

The use of *and* between young and pretty further emphasizes that each specifies a reason he dislikes them.

Stylistically, this sentence is quite good for its purposes -- presuming the purpose is not merely to convey that there is man who dislikes most pretty, young women.